# No se puede acceder a phpmyadmin tras su instalación en Ubuntu16

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, ubuntu

No puedo acceder a phpmyadmin para administrar bases de datos. Tras instalar phpmyadmin en Ubuntu16, veo que aparece en /etc/phpmyadmin/ con una serie de archivo en su interior, pero si desde un navegador del cliente voy a la URL http://192.168.3.16/phpmyadmin sale como página no encontrada. En cambio la página de bienvenida de Apache sí se visualiza.

EN el archivo apache.conf se ha añadido la fila: "Allowoverride All"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La página de apache de bienvenida se ve sin problemas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier página como el ejemplo de info.php se ve sin problemas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Intenta creando un enlace:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
 sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf
 sudo systemctl restart apache2
```